# Xamarin.Forms: Issue with text to speech feature for HTML data

Tags: xamarin.forms, text-to-speech, xamarin.essentials

I am using the `Label` for showing HTML data on UI with `TextType="Html"` property. That feature works well and on UI HTML content gets converted to normal text.

I am also implemented text to speech features using `Xamarin Essentials`. When the TTS function starts I am highlighting the corresponding text using [span property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754884/xamarin-forms-how-to-highlight-text-and-pause-play-audio-of-text-to-speech).

**When the TTS function starts, the normal text gets converted into HTML data. How I fix this issue?**

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SuvZ2TjuDixVjqhJnkEFYpYKWb4oLP-A/view?usp=sharing) for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be an expected effect because the content of string is html format .As a workaround , You could get the content of the html by using **Regex** .

```
public static string GetHtmlText(string html)
{
   html = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(html, @"<\/*[^<>]*>", "", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   html = html.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("&nbsp;", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("\n\n\n", "\n");
    return html;
}
```

So you could improve the code like following :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    string[] strList;
    public List<ChapterDetails> chapterDetails { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //normal text
        //string content = "Each platform supports different locales,\n to speak back text in different languages and accents.\n Platforms have different codes and ways of specifying the locale, \n  which is why Xamarin provides a cross-platform Locale class and a way to query them with GetLocalesAsync.\n ";

        //html text from epub file
        chapterDetails = new List<ChapterDetails>();
        string fileName = "Alices-Adventures-in-wonderland.epub";
        var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{fileName}");
        EpubBook epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(stream);
        foreach (EpubChapter chapter in epubBook.Chapters)
        {
            chapterDetails.Add(new ChapterDetails() { title = chapter.Title, htmlData = chapter.HtmlContent, subChapters = chapter.SubChapters });
        }
        string content = GetHtmlText(chapterDetails[0].htmlData);
        label.Text = content;
        string str = ".";
        char character = char.Parse(str);
        string str2 = ",";
        char character2 = char.Parse(str2);
        string str3 = "\n";
        char character3 = char.Parse(str3);
        strList = content.Split(new char[] { character, character2 , character3});
    }


    public static string GetHtmlText(string html)
    {
        html = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(html, @"<\/*[^<>]*>", "", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        html = html.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("&nbsp;", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("\n\n\n", "\n");
        return html;
    }

    private async void ClickedButton(object Sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strList.Length; i++)
        {
            
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strList[i]))
            {
                string content = strList[i];
                var formattedString = new FormattedString();
                for (int j = 0; j < strList.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (i == j)
                    {
                        formattedString.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = strList[j], ForegroundColor = Color.Black, BackgroundColor = Color.Gray });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        formattedString.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = strList[j], ForegroundColor = Color.Black, });
                    }
                }

                label.FormattedText = formattedString;
                label.TextType = TextType.Html;
                await TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync(content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note :** In this way the style of css will not work any more . You need to set the style (font or color) in span by yourself .

Comment: Working fine on android. On ios and windows platforms, when TTS starts the UI will be blank.

Comment: Set the `label.TextType = TextType.Html;`  to `label.TextType = TextType.Text;` .

Comment: UI blank issue gets resolved after adding TextType.Text; But in windows, the text highlight is not working. For android and ios, space between the words are not added properly. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c7btcxhD3_Pv_zCNbQqkzqGiFAyC12pd/view?usp=sharing